# Deploy two ASP.NET web api projects in the same solution separately

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, appveyor

I have two ASP.NET web api .csproject projects in the same solution. How can I configure the build/deployment steps in Appveyor so that they can be deployed to two separate IIS websites on my server?

If it means I have to create two projects in Appveyor, I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 2):

First, build should produce two artifacts (packages) - one for each application. Then you should setup either two deployment steps or two environments. Look at this guide for more details: http://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy